# Hahn-Banach theorem proof

Tags: functional-analysis, hahn-banach-theorem

I read the Brezis functional analysis, differential equations and Sobolev spaces textbook. We extend $g(x):G\to\mathbb{R}$ to $f(x):E\to\mathbb{R}$

The idea of the proof is to construct a well-ordered set of extension functions $g\leq h_1\leq h_2\leq\dots\leq f$ which domains are embedded $G\subset\dots\subset E$, and then by Zorn lemma have a maximal element of such set. It is rest to prove that the domain of the maximal element $Dom(f)$ is indeed equal to $E$. Further it goes by contradiction and we consider $x_0\notin Dom(f)$, but then we set
$$h(x+tx_0)=f(x)+\alpha t$$
and I don't understand how does one naturally come up with that setting

Comment: I don't quite understand the definition of $h$. Where does $\alpha$ come from? Where is the dependence on $x_0$? Or should $\alpha$ be $x_0$?

Comment: I think the last piece is "regular stuff", the genius was setting up a partial order on extensions and using zorn's lemma on it. It's not a coincidence that there are pretty big names attached to the theorem :)

Comment: @stange sorry for the late response and for the lack of precision, $h$ is a member of the ordered set, let us call it $P$. Since we supposed that $D(f)\neq E$, then we  take $Dom(h)=D(f)+\mathbb{R}_{x_0}$, also $\alpha\in\mathbb{R}$ chosen in a such way that $h\in P$, notice that $x_0\notin Dom(f)$, therefore there is no explicit dependence on it

Comment: @Daniele fair enough! I agree that the initial idea is outstanding (maybe because of it I get it and accepted easier)